# Async await flutter firestore

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to ask whats going on with my code.

Assuming the 'Counter' field is 179 in this instance, how do I make my outside myData update before printing?

```
    class Test {
      Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
      var myData;

      void getData() async {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
            await _firestore.collection('Counter').document('Counter').get();
        myData = await snapshot.data['Counter'];
        print('inside $myData');
      }

      void checkMyData() {
        myData = 5;
        getData();
        print('outside $myData');
      } 
    }
```

Console:

flutter: outside 5

flutter: inside 179

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `getData()` return a `Future` like this:

```
Future getData() async {
```

So you can do this:

```
getData().then((value) {
  print('value: $value');
}).catchError((error) {
  print('error: $error');
});
```

But you probably want to use a `FutureBuilder` to show the information when arrives, like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text('value: ${snapshot.data}');
    } else if (snapshot.hasError){
      return Text('error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return Text('loading...');
  },
)
```

Comment: May I then ask what If i have 2 variables i want to return?

Comment: You should have an object that contains these two variables